# Bamboo variable replacement in batch file

Tags: bamboo

We're running Atlassian's Bamboo build server 4.1.2 on a Windows machine. I've created a batch file that is executed within a Task. The script is just referenced in a .bat file an not inline in the task. (e.g. createimage.bat)

Within the createimage.bat, I'd like to use Bamboo's PLAN variables. The usual variable syntax is not working, means not replaced. A line in the script could be for example:

```
goq-image-${bamboo.INTERNALVERSION}-SB${bamboo.buildNumber}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I found this article :
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/66109/accessing-build-specific-variables-from-script-without-having-to-use-environment-variables-box-on-script-config-page

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using the internal [Bamboo variables](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Bamboo+variables) syntax, but the [Script Task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Script) passes those into the operating system's script environment and they need to be referenced with the respective syntax accordingly, e.g. (please note the underscores between terms):

- Unix - `goq-image-$bamboo_INTERNALVERSION-SB$bamboo_buildNumber`
- Windows - `goq-image-%bamboo_INTERNALVERSION%-SB%bamboo_buildNumber%`

Surprisingly, I'm unable to find an official reference for the Windows variation, there's only [Using variables in bash](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Bamboo+variables#Bamboovariables-Usingvariablesinbash) right now:

> Bamboo variables are exported as bash shell variables. All full stops
>   (periods) are converted to underscores. For example, the variable
>   bamboo.my.variable is $bamboo_my_variable in bash. This is related to
>   File Script tasks (not Inline Script tasks).

However, I've figured the Windows syntax from Atlassian's documentation at some point, and tested and used it as documented in [Bamboo Variable Substitution/Definition](https://utoolity.atlassian.net/wiki/x/CQApAQ):

> - these variables are also available as environment variables in the Script Task for example, albeit named slightly different, e.g.
>     $bamboo_custom_aws_cfn_stack_StringWithRegex (Unix) or
>     %bamboo_custom_aws_cfn_stack_StringWithRegex% (Windows)

Comment: I know this has been a while, so maybe things have changed. I tried %bamboo_buildNumber% and %bamboo.buildNumber% in a batch-file, but the result was an empty string.

Comment: @TigersEye120  just tested my script in Bamboo now and it's working. In Bamboo your script should be `%bamboo_buildNumber%`, but to use this variable\parameter in your batch file you'd need to pass it through when you call the batch file FROM Bamboo. Bamboo syntax (if I understand correctly) is not applicable outside of the Bamboo scope/plan.